# Change a unique Character on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, if-statement

`<span class="number1">10.00</span>`

simply, i want to replace the '.'(dot) for a ','(comma) using jQuery.

I've tried several forms to search the `$('.number1')` characters and replacing
it with a comma.

`<span class="number1">10.00</span>`

What if there is more than one Dot in the string?

Comment: You should change that before it ends up in the HTML. (Also, don't use jQuery.)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer.

```
$(".number1").text(function () {
return $(this).text().replace(/\./g, ","); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery for such a simple operation? What you need is a simple string manipulation. Adding a library so that you can type a few less characters to do something so basic seems hardly worth it.

What you really need the the plain old JavaScript **[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method.

Here's jQuery and non-jQuery ways to do it:

```js
// With jQuery:
console.log($(".number1").text().replace(".", ","));

// Without jQuery:
console.log(document.querySelector(".number1").textContent.replace(".", ","));

// When you need to replace all the . chars. in the string, you'll need to use
// a regular expression with .replace(). 

// The / / denote the delimiters of a regular expression
// The \. is the escape code for a .
// The g means do a global find/replace throughout the string

// With jQuery:
console.log($(".number1").text().replace(/\./g, ","));

// Without jQuery:
console.log(document.querySelector(".number1").textContent.replace(/\./g, ","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number1">10.00.00</span>
```

Comment: You don't have enough jQuery, please add more.

Comment: @TyQ. LOLOLOLLOL!

Comment: `$($)` - also some jQuery in you jQuery.

Comment: jQuerify it bro.

Comment: Oh god, i just ran that and it caused an infinite loop, with a 1GB RAM tab.

Comment: Hey, my toilet is overflowing. Be back in a second...I've got to unclog it with jQuery.

Comment: Somebody just said jQuery is a cancer. Cannot follow that, but…

Comment: @AjAX I wouldn't say "cancer", I would say more of a scourge against society.

Comment: Only if you cheekily tip vanilla Javascript into jQuery questions. %)P

Comment: @AjAX. But, how could you not since jQuery === JavaScript?

Comment: Totally. That is why news have to understand that. And that you come around with Javascript which is not on jquery.org.

Comment: What if there is more than one Dot in the string?

Comment: @Umberto: `replace(/\./g, ",")`

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution in vanilla js:

```
let spanNumber = document.querySelector('.number1')

let number = spanNumber.textContent

let newNumber = number.split('.').join(',')

spanNumber.innerHTML = newNumber
```

short version with replace:

```
let DOMElement = document.querySelector('.number1')
let string = DOMElement.textContent.replace('.',',')
DOMElement.innerHTML = string
```

Comment: Why the use of `.textContent` and `.innerHTML`? Why call `.split()` and `.join()` and create a new array, when you can just call `.replace()`?

Comment: you're rigth, i forgot the replace method, i use innerHTML because i think the OP want repalce the HTML content

Answer (score 0):

Just use built in DOM property innerHTML, instead of unecessary jQuery mambo jambo like:

```
var num1       = document.querySelector('.number1');
num1.innerHTML = num1.innerHTML.replace('.', ',');
```

InnerHTML is value between your HTML tags, and since its a string it has access to all String prototype methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn it to array by finding a dot delimiter with split method, then get it right back using join like:

```
 // Lets say that the value is 10.05.53.324.343
 var num1       = document.querySelector('.number1'); 
 num1.innerHTML = num1.innerHTML.split('.').join(','); // Outputs  10,05,53,324,343
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Intl.NumberFormat` object instead of replacing characters:

Perhaps you have other numbers on your content that you want to format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

But you can check a working example below that formats a number on US-EN format to pt-BR:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.number1'); 
var value = parseFloat(el.textContent);
var newValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(value);
el.innerHTML = newValue;
```

```html
<span class="number1">10.00</span>
```

Comment: By definition, a library isn't present in JavaScript. A library is something that you reference so you can use it. If it was already present in JavaScript, you wouldn't need to reference a library.

Comment: Edited. Removed the library part out of it.